# The difference between unsigned long and UINT64

Tags: c++, c, windows

What is the difference between `unsigned long` and `UINT64`?
I think they are the same, but I'm not sure.
The definition of `UINT64` is :

```
typedef unsigned __int64    UINT64
```

(by using StdAfx.h)

Comment: Is there a typo on your question ? You first state "unsigned long to UINT64 i think its the same" then you say: "the defenition of UINT64 is : typedef unsigned __int64 UINT64" which has no long anywhere to be seen.

Bit size of int, long, long long etc is implementation defined, so standards-wise there is no right answer, as for platform, even under Windows (since you mention StdAfx.h... ) it depends on win32 vs amd64... be more specific.

Comment: Keep in mind that the latest ISO draft standards have intN_t types for types of specific rather than minimum widths.

Comment: @paxdiablo intN_t yes, but the question was about UINT64 which is different and non-standard, hence I asking if there was a _typo_ on the question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UINT64 is specific and declares your intent. You want a type that is an unsigned integer that is exactly 64 bits wide. That this may be equal to an unsigned long on some platforms is coincidence.

Comment: This is not a best solution, you can use BIGint; range (-2^63 -2^63 -1).


In my project, i use UINT64(C#) and BIGINT(MySQL)

Comment: @SergioPerez - the question is specific to C++, not C#. There are platform considerations at play here.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard does not define the sizes of each of the types (besides `char`), so the size of `unsigned long` is implementation defined. In most cases I know of, though, `unsigned long` is an unsigned 32 bit type, while `UINT64` (which is an implementation type, not even mentioned in the standard) is a 64 bit unsigned integer in VS.

Comment: The standard doesn't define the size of `char` either, it's implementation defined using CHAR_BITS in limits.h.

Comment: You are right in §5.3.3/1 The result of `sizeof` is defined as the size in bytes of the argument, and at the same time it defines `sizeof(char)` to be `1`, which means that the size of `char` is one byte. But the size of a byte is not defined in the standard. In §1.7/1 it only says that it must be a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is undefined.

Comment: The standard defines the *minimum* sizes of the types (though it defines it in terms of the minimum ranges).  For `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` those minima are 8, 16, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively.  (By the way, it's `CHAR_BIT` - no S).

Comment: @caf: The current c++ standard does not define those minima at all. The C++0x Final Draft requires chars to be at least 8bit, but it does not require any minimal size for any other type, only a partial order. Are you referring to the C standard? (BTW, I have updated the answer to make explicit that it refers to the C++ standard, and not C)

Comment: They are in the C standard (in C99, §5.2.4.2.1).  This section of the ISO C standard is included in C++ standard by reference.

Comment: The current standard does not refer to C99, but rather to C89 (ISO/IEC 9899:1990), and within the C++ standard the size of the different integer types is basically undefined only a partial order is required, `char` is 1 byte, `int` must be able to hold [INT_MIN,INT_MAX] as defined in `climits`. the type `long long` does not even exist in the current C++ standard (it will in C++0x)

Answer (score 4):

The `unsigned long` type size could change depending on the architecture of the system you are on, while the assumption is that `UINT64` is definitely 64 bits wide. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Size

Answer (score 3):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.90).aspx

You want to see the difference between `unsigned long` and `unsigned __int64`.

Answer (score 1):

A `long` is typically 32 bits (but this may vary per architecture) and an `uint64` is always 64 bits. A native data type which is sometimes 64 bits long is a `long long int`.